# Does Tezos have any on-chain signature verification algorithms implemented?

Tags: operation

Does Tezos have any on-chain signature verification algorithms implemented?
Could it verify ECDSA/secp256k1 for example?

Answer (score 3):

It's called

> CHECK_SIGNATURE

in Michelson.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that would be possible with Tezos.

Comment: Hi @slarquie1 : please offer more detail to your answer as it is insufficient to represent a high quality answer! ;)